# 7u45 Java Applets: JVM Shared, not allowed to set security manager

Tags: java, security

After upgrading to java 7 update 45 we started receiving the following error when running the site.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JVM Shared, not allowed to set security manager
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPermissionHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.setSecurityManager0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(Unknown Source)
    at xxxx.init(xxxx.java:235)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.SecurityException: JVM Shared, not allowed to set security manager
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@3126d4
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 1 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@7ad4d5
```

Any ideas please to resolve this issue.

Comment: As alluded to in the exception message, one JVM process can typically run multiple applets. Clearly you don't want to be fiddling with globals in such a scenario. The security manager is a particularly sensitive global. There is a `separate_jvm` parameter, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I have multiple applets, so how to fix this